# Odd Python/Tkinter keybind class errors

Tags: python, class, tkinter, error-handling, key-bindings

Right now I'm attempting to bind the WASD keys to a player so that when pressed, a player will move in specific directions depending on what keys pressed. The problem is, whenever I press any keys, this error comes up and the "player" doesn't move.

```
File "main.py", line 143, in <module>

player.append(Player())

File "main.py", line 69, in __init__

root.bind('w', self.up)

AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'up'
```

the main code is below: (I dont know if some of the smaller bits are needed so apologies)

```
from tkinter import *
import random, math


root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,500)

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(100, 500)
        y = random.randint(0, 500)
        self.width = random.randint(75,100)
        self.player = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + self.width, y+self.width, fill="Blue")
        self.speed =50/self.width
        root.bind('w', self.up)
        root.bind('d', self.right)
        root.bind('s', self.down)
        root.bind('a', self.left)
    
      def getCoordsPlayer(self):
        return canvas.coords(self.player)
    
      def deleteplayer(self):
        canvas.delete(self.player)
    
    
      def moveplayer(self):
        left, top, right, bottom = self.getCoords()
        if left<0 or right > 500:
          def left(self, event):
            left, top, right, bottom = canvas.coords(self.player)
            canvas.move(self.player, -10, 0)
            canvas.update()
    
          def right(self, event):
            left, top, right, bottom = canvas.coords(self.player)
            canvas.move(self.player, 10, 0)
            canvas.update()
        if top<0 or bottom > 500:
          def up(self, event):
            left, top, right, bottom = canvas.coords(self.player)
            canvas.move(self.player, 0, -10)
            canvas.update()
    
          def down(self, event):
            left, top, right, bottom = canvas.coords(self.player)
            canvas.move(self.player, 0, 10)
            canvas.update()

canvas = Canvas(root,width=600,height=600,bg="white")
canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
    
player = []
for i in range(1):
    player.append(Player())
```

Comment: I think the error is due to the fact that you execute `root.bind('w', self.up)` before the `self.up` function is defined.

Comment: The error seems to be telling you exactly what is wrong: you haven't defined `self.up`. as a method on the object.Your functions are nested inside another function.